# Is groovy a potential development language for Android

Tags: android, groovy

I've recently started using groovy as an alternative to Java and I would like to develop Android apps in groovy. All the examples I have investigated seem to be quite old.

So I was wondering if it is possible to develop Android apps in groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a great idea, and it's been tried with partial success - there was a project called DiscoBot that had things partially working - see http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/groovy-grails/groovy-android

However, it's a difficult proposition though, both because of the size of the Groovy runtime, and because much of what Groovy does to implement a dynamic language is not fully supported by the Dalvik VM.

That said, it is being worked on.

I'm guessing that the reason that you got some 'close' votes here is because you could have found all of this information for yourself with a quick search in your favorite web search engine.

Comment: I had done a quick search and found DiscoBot but it looked out of date . I was hoping it had just been forked to somewhere. I do like groovy - coming from a perl background I find Java a bit too square. I had assumed that groovy converts groovy code into java behind the scenes. Obviously there is more to it than that

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn The actual answer is _"there have been two attempts, but there is currently no work being done in this area"_, Discobot was initiated a few years ago, then development stopped. It was then picked up again by another party, but then too stopped after they moved away from Android projects so had no need to keep working on it. It currently languishes in need of some love ;-)

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek, do you think it would be feasible to support at least static groovy? Sorry if this is nonsense, never tried android before :-)

Comment: @WillP - yes and no - I think that it's probably relatively easy to support it with static groovy, but completely static groovy looks pretty much like java - so I don't think it would provide much benefit.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek, but operator overload, closures, type inference, boolean/string coercion, native syntax for lists, maps and regex... And whatever more i can't remember; those can be static :-)