# Would Groovy work with ART on Android Lollipop OS?

Tags: android, groovy

I recently discovered the Groovy language and after a little googling it seems to be a good alternative to the current version of java for Android which is kind of old(based on jdk 7) and do not supports "case class", "trait" and more features that available in other jdk based languages like - scala, python, ruby and perl.

Groovy can help in creating more readable and maintainable code, and avoid NPEs and other exceptions but also runs slower due to some constraints integrating with Dalvik VM runtime(according to comments in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914010/is-groovy-a-potential-development-language-for-android)).

Now, that Google has released the new Android OS - Lollipop, that presents different architecture - ART, it's unclear whether we could still develop Android apps with groovy.

Comment: The answer is correct, Groovy will run on ART. BTW the thread you are referring to is old and irrelevant: Groovy now has official support for Android and runs the same speed as Java (as long as you use @CompileStatic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groovy files for Android are compiled into .class files like regular Java files, then they are dexed to become Dalvik (or ART) executables. 
So, ART won't change a thing.

There is an extremely clear and thorough explanation in this post from the creator of the Groovy for Android Gradle plugin: http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/06/grooid2.html